# Water Detection Sensor With Configurable Endpoint

Tags: internet-of-things, measurement-devices

I'm working on an IoT Project that monitor the temperature / humidity of a house and detect if there are water leaks.

Now, I'm looking for a water detection sensor with these constraint :

- Must be connected to Wi-Fi (with or without gateway)
- An administrator can control where the sensor send data (I want these data directly on my server endpoint)
- I want to be able use my application and not an external application

Comment: If you're using an IOT device wouldn't you only need the water sensor? I have a Rasp Pi equipped IOT device at work, and it acts like its own system, so I only end up worrying about receiving values from sensors and exposing data to the internet via software libraries from an IOT app (UWP in particular).

Comment: @BennettYeo I have build the backend of the project with a mobile application. I don't plan to create an IOT hub or device by myself because it's a lot of problem in production, so I'm just looking for a device that can send data to my server online (Via HTTP)

Comment: My gut instincts tell me that you probably won't be able to find a device as specific as that, with pre-made HTTP exposure functionality. Since Hardware Recs is better suited for answering questions about general computer hardware, perhaps it would be worth checking our affiliated [IOT Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) site. I'm not particularly familiar with that community so I would advise [familiarizing yourself with their rules](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to minimize chance of closure.

Comment: Check out WirelessTag.net.  They do have a moisture (leak) sensor (click the Buy Now button to find—website organization isn’t their strong point).  The only caveat is that there is dependency on wireless tags cloud server (no monthly fee tho).  Using the kumoapps feature you can push data to your own server.  I have 10 of the temp/humidity sensors.

Comment: @BennettYeo surprise, it basically exists. Not sure if it’s an exact fit for his need tho.